# MPAndroidChart add image on the right of the graph

Tags: android, charts, linechart, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to implement something like this [image]

using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).
I've managed to add the line (cubic style), but I have no idea how to set the circles and the texts on the right of the graph.

As far as I could see in the source code, I have to implement a custom Renderer for that, but I was wondering if there is a much simpler solution to that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no default solution** for the problem you are describing.

However, (as you already mentioned), a custom `Renderer` class will let you do almost anything, so I would get started by creating your own `Renderer` that does exactly what you want and set it for the chart.